# Live Rendering a custom component using IB_DESIGNABLE from a pod dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, ibdesignable

I'm having some difficulty using `IB_DESIGNABLE` in a pod.

I created a custom view which I marked as `IB_DESIGNABLE` and made a sample project that uses it. No problems so far.

The issue happens when adding that custom view as a pod dependency. Although the project builds and runs successfully, there is an error when the storyboard that uses the custom view is opened. The Live Rendering process starts and tries to show the view live inside Interface builder but it fails with the following error:

[image]

This is too bad because we lose Live Rendering which is, in my opinion, one of the best features from Xcode 6.

- Cocoapods gem version: **0.34.4**
- Xcode version: **6.1 (6A1052d)**

I've tried with other projects that use `IB_DESIGNABLE` and have a `podspec`:

1. https://github.com/Eddpt/EAColourfulProgressView (Class: `EAColourfulProgressView`)
2. https://github.com/hayashi311/HRButton (Class: `HRButton`)
3. https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK (Class: `ESTIndoorLocationView`)

Someone else had the same issue in [Estimote - Indoor Location Error](https://community.estimote.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202440003-Indoor-Location-Error) but the solution described means losing Live Rendering capabilities.

Has anyone been able to use a `IB_DESIGNABLE` component through Cocoapods?

Error: "failed to load designables from path (null)"

Comment: I have the same issue when the class having IB_DESIGNABLE is in a dependent project (e.g. framework project)

Comment: I have the same issue too. If "MyCustomView" is in my project, it works great, but if this class is in the Pods project it doesn't work anymore. I get the same error: "failed to load designables from path (null)" (I'm writing it here to find this thread more easily on Google ! ).

Comment: Any chance that importing the designable classes in a framework in the main project would fix it? Going to try that and report back.

Comment: Followup: framework didn’t work. I posted a sample project on this CocoaPods bug: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2792

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of [Cocoapods (0.36.0.beta.1)](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/0.36.0.beta.1).

To install this version:

`[sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre`

More information about Cocoapods with frameworks [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/)

In order to fix the `Error: "failed to load designables from path (null)"`:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'test' do
pod 'EAColourfulProgressView', '~> 0.1.0'
end

target 'testTests' do

end
```

Add **use_frameworks!** to you `Podfile`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's correct. Dynamic frameworks are only available in iOS 8 and there doesn't seem to be any way to make `IB_DESIGNABLE` work with static libraries. You could drag and drop the source files for the dependency in question instead of using cocoapods, if you really want `IB_DESIGNABLE` to work

Comment: if I use 'use_frameworks!'  This impacts my other library's pods error erros , can you suggest how I can apply this for only specific pod '' only.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying your custom class in the Identity Inspector, are you specifying from which module this class should be loaded? The module should be the name of the library the class comes from.

Comment: Modules only need to be specified if you are using Swift, not with Objective-C. My sample project uses Objective-C.

Comment: Does your library also have depencies on other frameworks which need to be located via @rpath? If that is the case, you should notice system logs in Console showing the failure that occured when resolving the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved my problem using `use_frameworks!` on the PodFile, in the first Line. (don't forget the `!`)

IBInspectable properties must be Dynamic, so it asks for a Dynamic Linkage of the Library. By using the above line, as soon as you set the class of a control, it will build the framework and link it, resolving this binding issues. When I upgraded to beta, Parse stopped working.

Hope it helps someone.